# ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA certificate error while recording in Jmeter 2.13

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, jmeter-plugins

I am getting Root CA certificate error while recording in Jmeter. I have tried all below mentioned google searched solutions but didn't helped.

- Installed Certificate which was created in bin folder.
- Added certificate in browser's trust certificate.
- Provided Java home in Jmeter.bat and Jmeter.properties file.
- Added java home and JRE path in Environment variables.
- Deleted certificate created in bin directory. Also deleted keystore file(proxyserver.jks)
- Renamed keystore file as jssecacerts.jks and kept in jre7\lib\security.
- By providing keytool utility path in system.properties.

Could anyone help me by giving accurate solution.

Error:
Root CA certificate: ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA created in Jmeter bin directory You can install it following instruction in component Reference documentation (see Installing Jmeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording paragraph) Please check the details below when installing the certificate in the browser

CN=_DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate(Jmeter root CA), OU =USername:AMIT,C=US figerprint(sHA1):75 38 f7 3d f5 bb 99 17 83 b7 ee 9f 06 6d 70 f3 92 bb c0 2c created: Mon Jul 12 11:05:02 PDT 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error.

Just an information message. If you did what it advises then just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, After ignoring this warning I am able to proceed with my recording.